# Nant build script automagical redirects folders

Tags: build-automation, nant

I have inherited a nant script from a previous colleague. It is used for among others building the application and distributing it to the sites in question (beta, live) called stage.

The property in question: `<property name="ftpRoot" value="build\ftp\" />`

I use the command `build publishToBeta / Live` pending which stage I'm at. I have `<target name="publishToBeta" />` and `<target name="publishToLive">` which takes the ftpRoot and makes a ftpFolder
`<property name="ftpFolder" value="${ftpRoot}Beta\" />` and ofcourse a Live too.

Looks good sofar.

At this point `${ftpFolder} = build\ftp\Beta` (for the beta stage)

Only problem is the website in question goes to `ftp://application/{stage}` to look for new version. From my(developer) end that is `\\ftpServer\ftp\application\{stage}`.

Somehow `build\ftp\beta` equals `\\ftpServer\ftp\application\beta` (and likewise with live)

I can not find the folder `build\ftp\{stage}` on my developer machine, and I can not find the script lines where it copies anything to the ftp server from my `c:\...\build\ftp\{stage}`.

Am I missing something? Can nant alias a virtual folder on my c:\ with a physical folder on the server? Does nant have automagical capabilities I have yet to discover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh, found it. A small bit referring to a new xml - containing a new `<property name="ftpRoot" value="\\ftpServer\ftp\{application}\" />`

Only took me a 2-3 days. Very well hidden.